# Error with User Sign up with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So I'm using the following JS function for signing up users on a website. It uses Parse. Currently, this function just automatically returns account not created after I fill up info and click on submit. `register-submit` is the id of a button. There are no error messages either on the console. I'm very new to javascript and parse and not sure where I'm messing up. Any help will be appreciated!

```
<script>
$(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#register-submit').on('click', function(event) {
     Parse.initialize("s1ySDCya6vuDDvFaxKgEGZLxOvdf8pfG4YMtvjcy", "KGJRCBGgvuyfoiqt8hakSJHODu1BeXtqqGNk0Hnl");
     var user = new Parse.User();

     var form = document.getElementById("register-form")

     var usernameVal = form.username.value; 
     var passwordVal = form.password.value; 
     var emailVal = form.email.value; 

     user.set('username',usernameVal);
     user.set('password',passwordVal);
     user.set('email',emailVal);

     user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
        form.submit();
        alert("Account Successfully Created!");

        }, error: function(user,error){
            alert("Account Not Created!");
        }
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

The form is structured like the following:

```
   <form id="register-form" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                            <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#register-form').submit(function(event) {
     Parse.initialize("s1ySDCya6vuDDvFaxKgEGZLxOvdf8pfG4YMtvjcy", "KGJRCBGgvuyfoiqt8hakSJHODu1BeXtqqGNk0Hnl");
     var user = new Parse.User();

     var form = document.getElementById("register-form")

     var usernameVal = form.username.value; 
     var passwordVal = form.password.value; 
     var emailVal = form.email.value; 

     user.set('username',usernameVal);
     user.set('password',passwordVal);
     user.set('email',emailVal);

     user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
        form.submit();
        alert("Account Successfully Created!");

        }, error: function(user,error){
            alert("Account Not Created!");
        }
    });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this, this time there is no alert message.. the form just refreshes.. thats it

Comment: Now I'm getting the "Account not created" alert... not sure why

Comment: just add console.log(error); before alert of account not created .. and post this error...

Comment: There was no error, but the problem was the null in `user.signUp`. I changed it to `usernameVal, passwordVal, ` and it worked. Thanks for your help though!